# Caching a page separately for users and guests?

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache, cache-handler

I've written a custom component and I'm trying to improve its performance by including Joomla's caching.
One view has additional detail which is only included for logged in users.

I've been selectively switching the caching on using the JControllerLegacy display() $cachable and $urlparams which works very well.

Question. Is there any way to get $urlparams to take into account login status (ie JFactory::getUser()->guest)?

At the moment I'm just caching if the user is a guest and turning it off for logged in.
I'd like it to cache both view variations.